# Get the data from the website to the python

Tags: python, pandas, web, url

I need to access the table from this website https://www.tsa.gov/coronavirus/passenger-throughput.

I need to have this table as a pandas data frame.

Before, I worked only with the URLs which are already the xls or csv, so I do not know how to get the table from the ordinary website.

Help, please!

Comment: use beautifulsoup to parse the html and extract the table: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/extracting-data-html-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to provide the starting point. you can check the [official documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for further details.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://www.tsa.gov/coronavirus/passenger-throughput',  headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
html = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    print(row)
```

output looks like this:

```
 <tr><td><strong>Date</strong></td><td><strong>Total Traveler Throughput</strong></td><td><strong>Total Traveler Throughput<br/>(1 Year Ago - Same Weekday)</strong></td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/21/2020</td><td>92,859</td><td>2,227,475</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/20/2020</td><td>99,344</td><td>2,594,171</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/19/2020</td><td>105,382</td><td>2,356,802</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/18/2020</td><td>97,236</td><td>1,988,205</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4/17/2020</td><td>106,385</td><td>2,457,133</td></tr>
```